# Can Chrome Remote Desktop be configured for unattended connections?

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-remote-desktop

There are two parts to my question of "unattenedness".

1. The ability to connect to the remote desktop without also having to magically be at the remote site to click the generate key button.
2. Likewise, not having to be at the remote site to click "Continue" every 30 minutes to prevent the connection from disconnecting.

The fact that I can't seem to find a simple answer when searching the web for help (like  being able to use a trusted pin), or even more complex solutions like generating certificates of trust, probably means, "it don't do that".

However, I'm hoping that the problem is that I just haven't figured out how to ask Google the right question yet. Hopefully someone here has some experience and insight into this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was doing that made it not not work:

When I downloaded and set up Chrome Remote Desktop (CRD) from the the Chrome Web Store, the chrome account I was logged in with was different on the remote and local computers (I use multiple email accounts for various tasks).  This blunder meant that, even though I could change the active account from within CRD, the client and host were not actually configured with the same base Chrome account (email address). So I was being prevented from using the remote access functionality on the “Remote Access” page of the extension (app). Once I corrected that, I was then able to connect using the pin I was prompted to create during setup.

To be more specific:

- I completely uninstalled CRD on one of mine boxen
- From within the Chrome browser, I logged into same Chrome account as the other box
- Then I went back to the Chrome Web Store and downloaded/installed CRD
- Then the “Remote Access” page showed the remote computer and let me use the direct access pin